# Page-specific JavaScript together with third-party scripts and application-wide scripts in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

TL;DR at the bottom.

I'm looking for a way to use Webpack like the way I'm using a Gulpfile right now.

My Gulpfile does the following:

1. It Uglifies bower components (like jQuery, Air datepicker, MomentJS) into a single file (vendors.min.js)
2. It concats every file in a specific folder, Uglifies the contents and processes it into another single file. (lib.min.js)
3. It watches a folder for new/changed files, takes only the changed file,  Uglifies it and saves it into a folder (these are my `app` files, they are page specific and can be loaded on demand).

So now I have 3 types of files:

1. #### vendors.min.js

   - Loaded on every page in my application.
   - These make sure all the required third-party scripts are always available when you need them.
2. #### lib.min.js

   - Loaded on every page as well.
   - This is my application's `'framework'` `'Library'`, it mostly looks for data-attributes on elements and binds datepickers, tooltips but also provides some utility functions like cleaning Strings, formatting Strings as money etc.
3. #### app/*.min.js

   - These give our developers a place to write page specific JavaScript.
   - They are loaded ONLY on that page.

#### I'm new to Webpack

I've watched a couple of video tutorials about it, I can see it is powerful and can help me to get further into JavaScript (read: use a more advanced structure and ES2015).
I've also read through the Webpack tutorial but can't find how to make it work for my structure.

So the question is:

## TL;DR

How can I use Webpack to have global (application wide) AND page-specific JavaScript in my applications and have them use third-party vendors (like jQuery, MomentJS, either through bower or npm or something).

Answer (score 4):

You should have a entry config for each page like this:

```
entry: {
    page1: ['./src/page1.js'],
    page2: ['./src/page2.js'],
}
```

And output like:

```
output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/app/`,
    filename: '[name].min.js',
},
```

And then use the CommonsChunkPlugin plugin to build a global file with things like jQuery, MomentJS

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors.and.lib.min.js'),
]
```

(This is for webpack version 1)